# How to reliably fetch large chunk of data from network node

Tags: python, sockets, twisted, paramiko

I need to connect to a network node, run a couple of commands and fetch their outputs into a log file. Currently I'm using the Paramiko library for this purpose. The code essentially uses the recv_ready() method on the channel object within a while loop, so its supposed to keep collecting the command output until the buffer is empty.

Here's the code (snippets from a class) for setting up the channel,

```
self.client = paramiko.SSHClient()
self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

self.client.connect(self.nw_host, username=self.nw_user, password=self.nw_pass, timeout=60)

# invoke interactive shell
self.channel = self.client.invoke_shell()
```

... and here's the code where I'm trying to fetch the output,

```
while self.channel.recv_ready():
    cmd_out_data += self.channel.recv(self.buffer_size)
```

The buffer_size is the chunk of data I'm receiving in one read (from the output buffer).

This setup runs fine except in the cases where the output of a command is really huge. In such large output cases, I'm unable to capture the entire output using recv, and parts of the output fall over into the output log of the next command.

I wanted to know if this is the correct method, and if not, the proper way of doing this in Paramiko? Also, can the Python Twisted library help me here? I'm new to Python and socket programming and any help would be great.

Comment: If you were going to use Twisted you would be using Conch and not Paramiko.  There's a way to do it there, too, but it's a pretty different setup :).